# How can I reference the same path from one command to the next?

Tags: shell, command-line

Is there a way that I could reference the same path from one command to the next? For example, I may want to list the contents of a specific folder:

`$ ls ~/Documents/some/dir`

Then, once I've done that, I may want to perform some action in that same directory:

`$ mv ~/Documents/some/dir/file.txt ~/Documents/other/dir`

Is there a way to, essentially, invoke that path without typing it again (or using some sort of auto-suggestion or auto-fill that I can do with .zsh)?

I vaguely remember reading about something along these lines but I don't remember what the technique is?

Comment: You're right, the answer is the `$_` variable (?). That is pretty much what I'm looking for although Stéphane's `insert-last-word` suggestion also helpful.

Comment: Stéphane mentioned the `$_` variable too ;-). The linked question also mentions the Alt-. shortcut. (When an existing question’s answers apply to a new question, we prefer linking them. It’s not supposed to reflect negatively on the new questions and answers, it’s just the way things are done here.)

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt, I saw that Stéphane mentioned the `$_` variable (although I did miss that the first time I read his answer). I appreciate the clarification and the link to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [`insert-last-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-insert_002dlast_002dword) widget which in `emacs` mode is bound to <kbd>Alt+_</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+.</kbd> by default.

So

```
$ ls ~/Documents/some/dir
$ ls Alt+_/file.txt Alt+_
```

Or you can use the [`$_` special variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-_005f), or csh-style [history expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion) (`!$`) if you prefer.

Comment: Is that only available in Emacs?

Comment: @PaulJacobson, in the _emacs_ editor mode of `zsh` which is the default unless you have set `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` to `vi` in which case, you'd get the `vi` mode.

Comment: Hah! I learned something new today. Thanks!